# Android: Custom binding adapter where view extends and implements

Tags: android, android-databinding, android-binding-adapter

I am trying to build a custom binding adapter for a generic view which extends `View` and implements `Checkable`. `RadioButton` is an example, but I would like to make it generic so that it works with other views that are checkable.

If I use a RadioButton it does work, however, if I use `<T> where T: View, T: Checkable` the compiler fails with this error: `data binding error ****msg:Cannot find the setter for attribute 'bind:checked' with parameter type`

This is my failing attempt:

```
@BindingAdapter("bind:checked")
fun <T> setChecked(view: T, customClass: CustomClass) where T: View, T: Checkable {
    view.isChecked = blah
}
```

And if I use RadioButton instead of T, it works.

Is there a way to make this generic?